# What are the parameters of a Wishart-Wishart posterior?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, conjugate-prior, wishart-distribution

When infering the precision matrix $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ of a normal distribution used to generate $N$ D-dimensional vectors $\mathbf{x_1},..,\mathbf{x_N}$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x_i} &\sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu, \Lambda^{-1}}) \\
\end{align}
we usually place a Wishart prior over $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ since the Wishart distribution is the conjugate prior for the precission of a multivariate normal distribution with known mean and unknown variance:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\Lambda} &\sim \mathcal{W}(\upsilon, \boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}) \\
\end{align}
where $\upsilon$ are the *degrees of freedom* and $\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}$ the *scale matrix*. To add robustness and flexibility to the model we put an hyperprior over the parameters of the Wishart. For instance, [Görür and Rasmussen](http://kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/GoeRas10_%5b0%5d.pdf) suggest:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\Lambda_0} &\sim \mathcal{W}(D, \frac{1}{D}\boldsymbol{\Lambda_x}) \\
\frac{1}{\upsilon-D + 1} &\sim \mathcal{G}(1, \frac{1}{D}) \\
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{G}$ is tha Gamma distribution.

**Question:**

in order to sample the posterior of $\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}$ 
\begin{align}
p(\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0 | X, \Lambda}, \upsilon, D, \boldsymbol{\Lambda_x}) \propto
\mathcal{W}(\boldsymbol{\Lambda} | \upsilon, \boldsymbol{\Lambda_0})
\mathcal{W}(\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0} |D, \frac{1}{D}\boldsymbol{\Lambda_x}) \\  
\end{align}

what is the family and parameters of this posterior?

**PS:**

Dropping all factors that do not depend on $\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}$ and identifying the parameters with the parameters of a Wihsart I get a Wishart with parameters:
\begin{align}
\upsilon' &= \upsilon + D\\
\boldsymbol{\Lambda'} &= \boldsymbol{\Lambda} + \boldsymbol{\Lambda_x}
\end{align}

which looks quite nice, but I am not confident at all since I don't find any example neither on books nor the internet.

**Erratum**:

Görur and Rasmussen suggest those hyperpriors over the Wishart parameters, but this equation:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\Lambda} &\sim \mathcal{W}(\upsilon, \boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}) \\
\end{align}

should be instead:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\Lambda} &\sim \mathcal{W}(\upsilon, \boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}^{-1}) \\
\end{align}

therefore solving the lack of conjugacy. If we want to keep $\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}$ then we should use the Inverse Wishart as a prior (see @Xi'an 's answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The product of the two densities in
$$
p(\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0 | X, \Lambda}, \upsilon, D, \boldsymbol{\Lambda_x}) \propto
\mathcal{W}(\boldsymbol{\Lambda} | \upsilon, \boldsymbol{\Lambda_0})
\mathcal{W}(\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0} |D, \frac{1}{D}\boldsymbol{\Lambda_x}) \\  
$$
leads to
\begin{align*}
p(\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0 | X, \Lambda}, \upsilon, D, \boldsymbol{\Lambda_x}) &\propto
|\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}|^{-\upsilon/2}\,\exp\{-\text{tr}(\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\Lambda})/2\}\\ &\times |\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}|^{(D-p-1)/2}\,\exp\{-D\,\text{tr}(\boldsymbol{\Lambda_x}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0})/2\}\\
&\propto|\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}|^{(D-\upsilon-p-1)/2}\,\exp\{-tr(\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\Lambda}+D\,\boldsymbol{\Lambda_x}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0})/2\}\,,
\end{align*}
which does not appear to be a standard density. To keep conjugacy of sorts, the right hierarchical prior on $\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}$ should be something like
$$
\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0}\sim\mathcal{IW}(\boldsymbol{\Lambda_0} |D, \frac{1}{D}\boldsymbol{\Lambda_x})\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Xi'an !, Actually the parameter in the likelihood should be $\mathbf{\Lambda_0^{-1}}$ (my fault, see edit). I just posted an answer using this and keeping the Wishart*Wishart.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, thanks to @Xi'an answer I could make the whole derivation. I will write it for a general case:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{W}(\mathbf{W} | \upsilon, \mathbf{S^{-1}} ) \times \mathcal{W}(\mathbf{S} | \upsilon_0, \mathbf{S_0})
\end{align}
where the $\mathbf{S^{-1}}$ is the key to conjugacy. If we want to use $\mathbf{S}$ then it should be :
\begin{align}
\mathcal{W}(\mathbf{W} | \upsilon, \mathbf{S} ) \times \mathcal{IW}(\mathbf{S} | \upsilon_0, \mathbf{S_0})
\end{align}

I'm doing the first case (please correct me if I am wrong):
\begin{align}
\mathcal{W}(\mathbf{W} | \upsilon, \mathbf{S^{-1}} ) \times \mathcal{W}(\mathbf{S} | \upsilon_0, \mathbf{S_0})
&\propto 
|\mathbf{S}|^{\upsilon/2} \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} tr(\mathbf{SW}) \}\\
&\times 
|\mathbf{S}|^{\frac{\upsilon_0 - D -1 }{2}} \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} tr (\mathbf{S_0^{-1} S})\}\\
&\propto 
|\mathbf{S}|^{\frac{\upsilon + \upsilon_0 - D -1 }{2}} \exp\{-\frac{1}{2} tr ( (\mathbf{W} + \mathbf{S_0^{-1}) S})\}
\end{align}

where we used the fact that $tr({\mathbf{SW}}) = tr({\mathbf{WS}})$. By inspection, we see that this is a Wishart distribution:
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{S} | \cdot) = \mathcal{W}(\upsilon+ \upsilon_0, \mathbf{(W+S_0^{-1})^{-1}})
\end{align}

**Extension for $N$ draws $\mathbf{W_1...W_N}$**:

For the case when we have $N$ precision matrices then the likelihood becomes a product of $N$ likelihoods and we get:

\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{S} | \cdot) = \mathcal{W}(N \upsilon+ \upsilon_0, (\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{W_i+S_0^{-1})^{-1}})
\end{align}